# Why I can't get a pie diagram from dataframe. TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I can't get a pie diagram out of the Datafame/ Instead i gor an error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__

tables = pd.read_html("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1541617/000110465920125814/xslForm13F_X01/infotable.xml")

ren=tables[3]
ren.drop(ren.index[[0,1,2]], inplace=True)
ren[3] = pd.to_numeric(ren[3], errors='coerce') 
ren.sort_values([3],ascending=False, inplace=True)
ren = ren[[0,3,4]]
ren.rename(columns={0: 'Company', 3: 'Value (x$1000)', 4: 'Quantity'}, inplace=True )
ren = ren.set_index('Company')
print(ren)
ren.plot.pie(subplots=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLbZ1.png)

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values in column 4 "Quantity" are strings and not numbers. You need to convert those using `to_numeric()` like you did for column 3